# Database query interruption

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, spring-jdbc, futuretask

I have start some process in new thread:

```
FutureTask<?> futureTask = new FutureTask<Void>(() -> {
               startSomeProcess();
            }, null);
```

In `startSomeProcess` method I generate report for each item:

```
for (Item item : items) {
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                logger.info("currentThread isInterrupted");
                return;
            }
             generateReport(item);
     }
```

In `generateReport()` method I execute some select to DB and generate excel report from `ResultSet`:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString(),
                    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE)) {
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                //and fill excel from rs 
                 ...
```

But My `ps.executeQuery();` can execute a long time(1 sec- 999999h.
I have cancel button. If it press I make this

```
futureTask.cancel(true);
```

and check exception in `startSomeProcess();` method. But I can not check and interupt `ps.executeQuery();`. When I make `futureTask.cancel(true);` this `executeQuery` throw exception. But I am not configure this. It is automaticly.

My quations:  when I interupt the thread - Can I or do I have myself interrupt the query to the database, or it just happens and I have to handle the error only?

EDIT:

User send command - "cancel report generate". I faind futureTask and call `cancel()` method. and break build report. But if ps.executeQuery(); already start - I do not know how break it

Answer (score 3):

> My questions: when I interrupt the thread - Can I or do I have myself interrupt the query to the database, or it just happens and I have to handle the error only?

Interrupting the thread only sets a flag on the thread which causes only those methods that throw `InterruptedException` to do so.  In this case the SQL methods don't throw `InterruptedException` so just calling `future.cancel(true)` will not work.

If you are trying to cancel a running SQL query then you are going to need to this at a JDBC level by [canceling the underlying `Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel()).  To quote from the javadocs of `Statement.cancel()`:

> Cancels this Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support aborting an SQL statement. This method can be used by one thread to cancel a statement that is being executed by another thread.

So in your case, this means that another thread is going to have to do the canceling of your `ps`.  I'd create an object that wraps your `generateReport()` method that puts the `PreparedStatement ps` into a `volatile` field.  Then when the method executes the `ps` it does so from the field and another thread could call `cancel()` on the object which calls `ps.cancel()`.

It is important to note that query cancelation is SQL database and JDBC driver dependent.  Not all databases support it.

Answer (score 1):

> when I interupt the thread - Can I or do I have myself interrupt the query to the database, or it just happens and I have to handle the error only?

Once `executeQuery` starts, it can be stopped using [cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel()) method.

Other way is to handle exception or use [setQueryTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: How can I get PreparedStatement object in controller if it placed controller->new thread->first service->second service-> PreparedStatement object

Comment: use setQueryTimeout - is bad solution. I can have big query. I need stop execute only bu user press button

Comment: @user5620472 You need to design the cancellation service too.

Comment: @user5620472 `setQueryTimeout` i suggested as a way to cancel the query in general way not specific to your question, so that you can think about to use it if it can fit in your design with little alter.

Comment: I'm talking about it and asking. I implemented the interupt of execution thread. if the thread is interupted - I break my cycle and return. But I can not understend how can I get PreparedStatement  and call cancel() method

Comment: Why not create a list of `PreparedStatements`? pick the required object from this list to call cancel on it. You'll have to mark the object with some identifier.

Comment: I update question. PreparedStatements placed in controller-> serviceA->serviceB