# Java cancel task running Oracle query through JDBC - connection broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002) IO Error: Socket read interrupted

Tags: java, jdbc

Starting from [Java custom ThreadPool - pause task submission and cancel current queued tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78232916/java-custom-threadpool-pause-task-submission-and-cancel-current-queued-tasks) I'm implementing a mechanism to close ongoing queries on a specific connection for a period of time. Underlying JDBC connection pool is assured by HikariCP. Ongoing queries are cancelled by calling preparedstatement close as described here [Database query interruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483480/database-query-interruption).
Even doing so I'm getting the following error:

```
Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@4bc28c33 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)

marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read interrupted
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:821)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: Socket read interrupted
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.handleInterrupt(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:258)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:180)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:555)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:258)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:190)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:132)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:105)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:764)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:429)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:407)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I lost a day on this issue I will post the solution for others: running the application using

> -Doracle.jdbc.javaNetNio=false

fix the issue.

From [here](https://support.tibco.com/s/article/java-io-InterruptedIOException-Operation-interrupted):

> The 12.2.0.1 and above JDBC driver uses Java NIO calls in blocking
> mode, which may be impacted by any interrupt() calls being made by the
> application. This differs from previous versions of the JDBC driver,
> which used stream-based I/O API calls that were not affected by calls
> to interrupt(). This is a deliberate / intentional change beginning in
> the 12.2.0.1 JDBC driver.   Inspect the application code for any
> interrupt() method calls.
>
> Alternatively, set the following connection property:
> oracle.jdbc.javaNetNio=false in application tra file Example:
> -Doracle.jdbc.javaNetNio=false
>
> This will direct the JDBC driver to revert to the  pre-12.2 behavior
> of using stream-based I/O API calls no affected by interrupt() method
> calls.